# Complains "cannot construct the infinite type" when applying churchNumbers on multi-parameter functions

Tags: haskell, lambda, functional-programming, ghc

I want to use churchNumber to reduce code like these：

```
f = ((.) . (.) . (.))
```

to

```
f = churchNumber 3 (.)
```

but the ghc compiler complains these:

> pointfree.hs:24:29:
>      Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b ~ a0 -> b
>      Expected type: (b -> c) -> b -> c
>        Actual type: (b -> c) -> (a0 -> b) -> a0 -> c
>      Relevant bindings include
>        pointfree3 :: (b -> c) -> b -> c (bound at pointfree.hs:24:1)
>      In the second argument of ‘churchNumber’, namely ‘(.)’
>      In the expression: churchNumber 3 (.)
>
> pointfree.hs:24:29:
>      Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: c ~ a0 -> c
>      Expected type: (b -> c) -> b -> c
>        Actual type: (b -> c) -> (a0 -> b) -> a0 -> c
>      Relevant bindings include
>        pointfree3 :: (b -> c) -> b -> c (bound at pointfree.hs:24:1)
>      In the second argument of ‘churchNumber’, namely ‘(.)’
>      In the expression: churchNumber 3 (.)

and here is my complete code:

```
--{-# LANGUAGE #-}

import Control.Arrow

type Point = (Float, Float)
data RegularPolygen = RegularPolygen Int Float Point deriving (Show)

outline (RegularPolygen n r o) = [let (i', n') = (($i) &&& ($n)) fromIntegral; theta = (i' * 2.0 * pi / n') in (r * sin theta, -r * cos theta) | i <- [0..n-1]]


calc n r o = outline (RegularPolygen n r o)
calc' n r = (.) outline (RegularPolygen n r)
calc'' n = ((.) . (.)) outline (RegularPolygen n)
calc''' = ((.) . (.) . (.)) outline RegularPolygen
--calc'''' = (churchNumber 3 (.)) outline RegularPolygen
ps = calc''' 4 1 (0, 0)

---- The definition of churchNumber ----

churchNumber :: (Arrow a) => Int -> a b b -> a b b
churchNumber n f = if n == 0 then returnA else f >>> churchNumber (n - 1) f

a = churchNumber 3 (+1) 0
pointfree3 = churchNumber 3 (.)
--pointfree n = churchNumber n (.)
--f = pointfree 1 (+1) (+)
--x = f 1 2
```

Is there any way to make that work?

---

If we observe the type of `(.)`, `((.) . (.))`, `((.) . (.) . (.))` etc. , we got that:

```
(.)
    :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c

((.) . (.))
    :: (b -> c) -> (a -> a1 -> b) -> a -> a1 -> c

((.) . (.) . (.))
    :: (b -> c) -> (a -> a1 -> a2 -> b) -> a -> a1 -> a2 -> c

((.) . (.) . (.) . (.))
    :: (b -> c) -> (a -> a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> b) -> a -> a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> c
```

And if transform them to things below, you can find that they **almost have the same type**, do they really have the same type??

```
(.)
    :: (b -> c) -> (f b) -> (f c) where f b = (a -> b)

((.) . (.))
    :: (b -> c) -> (f b) -> (f c) where f b = (a -> a1 -> b)

((.) . (.) . (.))
    :: (b -> c) -> (f b) -> (f c) where f b = (a -> a1 -> a2 -> b)

((.) . (.) . (.) . (.))
    :: (b -> c) -> (f b) -> (f c) where f b = (a -> a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> b)
```

Comment: It looks like the actual output type of `churchNumber` is determined by the `Int` parameter, which can't really work?

Comment: Yes, that's really what happend, Is there any way to make things work?

Comment: I believe church numerals and stuff like that work mostly in the untyped lambda calculus, and need some adjusting when you apply them to a typed language.

Comment: There might be some way to do this if you write `3` using Peano naturals and you define a custom type class/type family. But I fear it would be quite ad-hoc for this case and quite inconvenient, unless you really need to generalize this to many other cases.

Comment: `churchNumber n f` must have the same type as `f`. You can compose e.g. `(+1)` how many times you want, and the composition still has the same type: `Num a => a -> a`. If you compose `(.)`, the type grows with the number of compositions - compare `:t (.)` and `:t ((.) . (.) . (.))`. (I don't know how to solve it - you might be able to introduce a data type that acts like a "trampoline" between the types.)

Comment: Your addition at the end is wrong, you cannot group (for example) `(a -> a1 -> a2 -> a3 -> b)` as `(a''' -> b) where a''' = a -> a1 -> a2 -> a3`.